# How do I add a select button to this list please?

Tags: html, select

How do I change this list from a drop down list that automatically changes to the URL in the drop down field, to a drop down list where the user has to select a green "select" button?

Thank you,
Steve.

```
<select name="cars" id="dynamic_select">
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Borrowing-Power-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Borrowing Power Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Loan-Repayment-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Loan Repayment Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Lump-Sum-Repayment-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Lump Sum Repayment Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Extra_Repayment_Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Extra Repayment Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Budget-Planner.aspx?ID=MFAA">Budget Planner</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Loan-Comparison-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Loan Comparison Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/How-Long-to-Repay-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">How Long to Repay Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Split-Loan-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Split Loan Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Property-Selling-Cost-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Property Selling Cost Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Property-Buying-Cost-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Property Buying Cost Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Saving-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Saving Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Term-Deposit-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Term Deposit Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Stamp-Duty-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Stamp Duty Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Credit-Card-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Credit Card Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Income-Tax-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Income Tax Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Reverse-Mortgage-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Reverse Mortgage Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Leasing-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Leasing Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Home-Loan-Offset-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Home Loan Offset Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Honeymoon-Loan-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Honeymoon Loan Calculator</option>
  <option value="http://www.visionabacus.com/Finance/Australia/1/SuiteA100/640/Comparison-Rate-Calculator.aspx?ID=MFAA">Comparison Rate Calculator</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#dynamic_select').on('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Please edit your question and add some clarity as I also cannot understand your desired end result.

Comment: try $(document).on('change','#dynamic_select',function(){});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this out:**

```
<select name="cars" id="dynamic_select">
  <option value="https://google.com">google.com</option>
  <option value="https://google.de">google.de</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
  $('#dynamic_select').on('change', function () {
      var url = $(this).val();
        window.location = url; 
  });
```

**Update:**

```js
 $('#Submit').on('click', function () {
      var url = $('#dynamic_select').val();
        window.location = url;
        alert(url); // remove this line later
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cars" id="dynamic_select">
  <option value="https://google.com">google.com</option>
  <option value="https://google.de">google.de</option>
</select>
<input id="Submit" value="Go" type="submit"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @jiff. That's not what I really want. I would like a select button to the right of the list.

Comment: If I understand right, you want add a submit button beside select box then user can select a option then press the submit and then redirect to url, right?

Comment: Correct @jiff. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @jiff, I changed `id=Submit` to `<input id="Submitgo" type="submit" />` and updated the `<script>` as well, but now the submit button won't work.

See [here](http://pastebin.com/CsfsPSLp) for my new code.

Comment: @Steve look at the end of your code, where i wrote a comment for you i mean  _remove this line later_ , ok? this-> `});`  commented mistaken. remove my comment. your script should be like this: `$('#Submitgo').on('click', function() {
  var url = $('#dynamic_select').val();
  window.location = url;
  alert(url);
});
`

Comment: Thanks so much @jiff.